# How to display hierarchical and non-hierarchical taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created custom post type and 4 taxonomies. First, second and third taxonomy is hierachical, the last is not. Is there any possibility to display separetly hierarchical and non-hierarchical taxonomies, without using their names?

For better understand:
CPT has 4 taxonomies. 1, 2 and 3 are hierarchical, 4 taxonomy is non-hierachical. Now in span#one I want to display all hierarchical terms and in span#two all non-hierarchical terms of specific post.

How can I do that?

Comment: the OP is not clear about what he want to achieve please explain the things more clearly

Comment: Do you want to display all terms from these taxonomies or only the terms assigned to current post?

Comment: What are you having trouble with, specifically? Terms assigned to a post need to be output separately for each taxonomy anyway, so you'd just put them in different elements. Are you just having trouble listing terms at all?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż take a look above I updated my post. I just want to separate hierarchical and non-hierarchical terms of specific post.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, get taxonomies registered for a given type of post with [`get_object_taxonomies()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies). Then check which ones are hierarchical, e.g. using [`is_taxonomy_hierarchical()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy_hierarchical) [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). The last step is to display the lists.

```
// current post ID
$post_id = get_the_ID();
// taxonomies registered for this type of posts
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() );

$taxs_tree = [];   // hierarchical taxonomies
$taxs_flat = [];   // non-hierarchical taxonomies
foreach ( $taxonomies as $tax )
{
    if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $tax ) )
        $taxs_tree[] = $tax;
    else
        $taxs_flat[] = $tax;
}
```

Get terms from each taxonomy and display them.

```
// get terms as links
$terms_flat = $terms_tree = [];
foreach ( $taxs_tree as $tax ) {
    $terms_tree[] = get_the_term_list( $post_id, $tax );
}
foreach ( $taxs_flat as $tax ) {
    $terms_flat[] = get_the_term_list( $post_id, $tax );
}

echo '<span id="one">';
foreach ( $terms_tree as $links ) {
   echo $links;
}
echo '</span>';
```

Or:

```
//
// terms assigned to post, ordered by name, from all hierarchical taxonomies
$args = [
   'taxonomy'   => $taxs_tree,   // here you can pass array of taxonomies
   'object_ids' => get_the_ID(), // get only terms assigned to this post (current post)
   //'orderby.  => 'name',       // default
];
$terms_tree = get_terms( $args ); // array of WP_term objects

//
// terms assigned to post, ordered by name, from all non-hierarchical taxonomies
$args['taxonomy'] = $taxs_flat;
$terms_flat = get_terms( $args ); // array of WP_term objects

//
// display 
echo '<span id="one">';
foreach ( $terms_tree as $term ) {
    $link = get_term_link( $term );
    if ( is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
}
echo '</span>';

// the same with $terms_flat
```

The second solution (with `get_terms`) sort terms **from all** hierarchical taxonomies by name, while the first one (with `get_the_term_list`) sort terms **from each** hierarchical taxonomy **separately**.

---

References:

- get_terms() - [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters)
- [get_term_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/)
- [get_the_term_list()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)